# Right align number column in tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

It must be simple and has been implemented but could not find anywhere. How can print a tibble with numeric column aligned right? I have tried several ways such as,

```r
df <- tibble(
    col1 = rnorm(10) * sample(100, 10),
    col2 = rnorm(10) * sample(100, 10)
)
print(df, align = "right")
print(df, pillar.align = "right")
```

If I convert to usual `data.frame` then it defaults to right align for a numeric column.

Comment: Is `print.data.frame(df, right = TRUE)` returning you the expected output?

Comment: If it is the case of data.frame, I think it already has a right-aligned numeric column by default. But not with the `tibble`.  With your solution, it will convert to a data frame.